# Selenium WebDriver: I want to overwrite value in field instead of appending to it with sendKeys using python

Tags: python, selenium

In WebDriver, if I use sendKeys it will append my string to the value that already exists in the field. I can't clear it by using clear() method because the second I do that, the webpage will throw an error saying that it has to greaterthan 1. So I can't clear it or an error will be thrown before I can put in the new value using sendKeys, and if I sendKeys it just appends it to the value already there.

Is there anything in WebDriver that lets you overwrite the value in the field?

Answer (score 0):

No, basically `.clear()` should work. but I have faced this issue several time it just does not work. Also what do you mean by

> will throw an error saying that it has to greaterthan 1.

There's an alternate way, which is basically to do control + A to select all the text and then press backspace.

**code :-**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

where element is web element, in your case your input field.

Comment: What are thw library files we need for this

Comment: This should be imported `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`, updated above as well.

Comment: How we can define elemnt for name housetax

Comment: I do not know what exactly you asked but I think, `driver.find_elements_by_name('housetax')` should work, plus do not ask different question/out of scope question in comment section, try to submit a new ticket instead.